# how to generate an xml with name value pair from key value paired xml?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i have an XML generated in the below form from JSON to XML Conversion.

```
<entry>
  <string>dataset_code</string>
  <string>GDP</string>
</entry>
```

How to convert this into the below format in XML?

```
<entry>
  <dataset_code>GDP</dataset_code>
</entry>
```

Note: Here the key-value pairs(dataset_code, GDP, entry) are dynamic.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In wich language do you want to do it? Java,C,C++, Tag also a language

Comment: could this be done in the xml itself by applying the xslt? if not, i would prefer java only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT, this would be done as:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="{string[1]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="string[2]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this can easily fail if the first string is not a valid XML element name.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is simply solved my issue. below is the code that i wrote to make it generic.                                                                               <xsl:template match="./*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="{*[1]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="*[2]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but playing with http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html I've found this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <entry>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="(entry/string)[1]"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="(entry/string)[2]"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>/<xsl:value-of select="(entry/string)[1]"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
  </entry>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Marco, thanks for responding on this. it looks working. but i cannot hardcode the "entry" text as well. this is also dynamic value. Apologies for not mention this before.