# how to restructure the xml with xslt for list type of elements to an element

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i have an XML generated in the below form from JSON to XML Conversion.

Full Original XML examples:

Example1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linked-hash-map>
   <entry>
      <string>dataset</string>
      <linked-hash-map>
         <entry>
            <string>id</string>
            <string>120140</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>dataset_code</string>
            <string>GDP</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>column_names</string>
            <list>
               <string>DATE</string>
               <string>VALUE</string>
            </list>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>frequency</string>
            <string>quarterly</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>type</string>
            <string>Time Series</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>premium</string>
            <boolean>false</boolean>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>data</string>
            <list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-07-01</string>
                  <double>18675.3</double>
               </list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-04-01</string>
                  <double>18450.1</double>
               </list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-01-01</string>
                  <double>18281.6</double>
               </list>
            </list>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>database_id</string>
            <int>118</int>
         </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
   </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

Example 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linked-hash-map>
   <entry>
      <string>dataset</string>
      <linked-hash-map>
         <entry>
            <string>dataset_code</string>
            <string>AAPL</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>column_names</string>
            <list>
               <string>DATE</string>
               <string>Open</string>
               <string>High</string>
               <string>Low</string>
               <string>Close</string>
            </list>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>frequency</string>
            <string>quarterly</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>type</string>
            <string>Time Series</string>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>data</string>
            <list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-07-01</string>
                  <double>116.45</double>
                  <double>117.1095</double>
                  <double>116.4</double>
                  <double>116.73</double>
               </list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-04-01</string>
                  <double>18450.1</double>
                  <double>113.1095</double>
                  <double>112.4</double>
                  <double>100.73</double>
               </list>
               <list>
                  <string>2016-01-01</string>
                  <double>18281.6</double>
                  <double>157.1095</double>
                  <double>136.4</double>
                  <double>156.73</double>
               </list>
            </list>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>database_id</string>
            <int>218</int>
         </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
   </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

the below part needs to be converted in both the xmls.

```
<entry>
       <string>column_names</string>
        <list>
          <string>DATE</string>
          <string>VALUE</string>
        </list>
</entry>
     <entry>
            <string>data</string>
            <list>
              <list>
                <string>2016-07-01</string>
                <double>18675.3</double>
              </list>
              <list>
                <string>2016-04-01</string>
                <double>18450.1</double>
              </list>
             </list>
    </entry>
```

How to convert this into the below formats?

1.

```
  <entry>
       <Date>2016-07-01</Date>
            <Value>18675.3</Value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <Date>2016-04-01</Date>
            <Value>18450.1</Value>
         </entry>
```

2.

```
<entry>
    <Date>2016-07-01</Date>
    <Value>18675.3</Value>
    <Date>2016-04-01</Date>
    <Value>18450.1</Value>
    </entry>
```

Note: All the data(Date, Value,data,entry,etc) are dynamic here.

Looking for a generic implementation of XSLT to bring the desired output. if not possible with xslt, then would like to go for Java to convert this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.``

Comment: Hmmm, could You elaborate on this: _All the data(Date, Value,data,entry,etc) are dynamic here_. Could You describe the rules for the transformation. For example: "always skip the first XML Element..."

Comment: **1.** The input you show us is not well-formed XML (has not single root element). -- **2.**. It's hard to believe that **all** element names are "dynamic". In any case, we need some rules here.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for looking into this. Apologies for confusion. the column names ("Date", "Value") are dynamic. as we are not sure about how many columns would be coming up in that list and what the text it would be. Also, the next array "data" name is also not static. this could be come as data set or some thing else. what i understand is, the header(column names list) and data are coming in 2 lists and we need to merge both of these lists in to a single array or flat element. and remove the individual lists from the xml. so that we could see that these column names when we generate an xsd.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for looking into this. Apologies for the confusion. it will have a root element. i have posted  some information about the dynamic data above. please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Can you provide another sample to show the dynamic nature? Usually, first few repeating nodes like `<entry>` help construct a generalized script.

Comment: Hi Parfait, Thanks for checking. i have updated the post with examples. hope this will help to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet will work for both your examples. I don't think it needs to be any more generic than that - and if it does, I don't see how.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/linked-hash-map">
    <xsl:variable name="col-names" select="entry/linked-hash-map/entry[string='column_names']/list/string" />
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry/linked-hash-map/entry[string='data']/list/list">
            <xsl:variable name="current-row" select="." />
            <entry>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-names">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:element name="{.}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$current-row/*[$i]" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365836/how-to-generate-an-xml-with-name-value-pair-from-key-value-paired-xml), this assumes that the supplied column names are valid XML element names.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Correct. you had helped me on the previous one as well. it does worked for me. Could you please help club both of these together and provide the final style sheet. the orignal example xml has been posted in the topic here.

Comment: The two answers are incompatible, because the two inputs are very different: here you have a list of column names and a separate list of values for each row; there you had the name and the value as a pair of sibling nodes.

Comment: Hi Michael, While creating the element, how to replace a space or special characters with _ if the column_names values are comes like this. "Adj.  open", "Split Ratio"?

Comment: Use the `translate()` function.